# spresense プログラムが数日動いて動かなくなる

Tags: spresense

(１)
Arduino IDEを使いCプログラムを書いていますが、プログラムを連続で動かし続けると数日動いた後に動かなくなってしまいます。
NuttX OS 含めてプログラムが動かなくなっているのか、NuttX OSの影響はなく、作成したプログラムが動かないのか分かりません。ストップしてしまう原因がどこにあるか調べたいのですが、調べる方法はあるでしょうか。
１日１回、CプログラムからLowPower.reboot() を使い、リセットをしています。
質問に過不足ありましたら別途回答を致します。

(２)
連続で１０日程度動かしますが、動かなくなってしまいます。
遠隔にハードウェア(spresense)を置き、動かなくなったことは、データがネットワークに上がらなくなった事で知ります。

(３)

```c
{
      //時間範囲の指定
      int startHour = 01;
      int startMin = 00;
      int endHour = 01;
      int endMin = 30;

      //現在時刻が範囲内かどうかを判定。範囲内であればデバイスリセット

      // 定期リセットデバッグ
      if (isTimeWithRange(*timeInfo, startHour, startMin, endHour, endMin)){
        std::cout <<"現在時刻は01:00~01:30の範囲内です" << std::endl;
        printf("Reboot...\n");
        delay(1000*60*15);
        LowPower.reboot();
      } else {
        std::cout <<"現在時刻は01:00~01:30の範囲外です" << std::endl;
      }
    }
}

bool isTimeWithRange(const std::tm& time, int startHour, int startMin, int endHour, int endMin){
  int hour = time.tm_hour;
  int min = time.tm_min;
 
  if (hour == startHour && min >= startMin && min <= endMin) {
      return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: アプリケーションは通信手段やデバイス、電源に何を使っていますか？リセット動作に問題があるように思えませんので、問題があるとしたら接続しているデバイスとそれらを制御しているアプリケーションにあるように思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。ご指摘いただいた内容について調査、確認しますので、進展がありましたらまた書き込みを致します。

Comment: 「データがネットワークに上がらなくなった事で知ります」では現象の説明として十分ではありません。詳しくなく、憶測でしないいのですが、DHCPはIPを貸与するプロトコルで所定期間以上は貸与できなかった気がします。もしDHCPをお使いなら何らかの理由で延長されておらず、有効期限切れとかは考えられませんか？もう少し原因を絞り込むための現象発生時の取得情報が必要です。